# Asp.net webfroms Google login not working

Tags: asp.net, webforms, google-signin

I have the project and users are login into their account by using Google login I created another project in the Google console developer portal to login with gmail now I got this below error message

> Code: 403 Message: Legacy People API has not been used in project {PROJECTID} before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting [https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project={PROJECTID}](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=%7BPROJECTID%7D) then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

I followed this URl and `https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project={PROJECTID}`
but the page show up this below error many times I click on Retry button nothing has changed.

[Error alert in Google Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79DNS.jpg)

I have followed this articles https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Login-with-Google-Account-API-in-ASPNet-and-get-Google-Plus-Profile-details.aspx

The code

```
 GoogleConnect.ClientId = "CODE-1545454545545bpqhocrakp.apps.googleusercontent.com"
 GoogleConnect.ClientSecret = "KHDFIUHUHDJHSLDSKJ"

 GoogleConnect.RedirectUri = "https://mywebsitedomain.com/Login"


 Dim code As String = Request.QueryString("code")
                Dim json As String = GoogleConnect.Fetch("me", code)
                Dim profile As GoogleProfile = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of GoogleProfile)(json)
```

Comment: The error says it might be disabled. Are you sure it isn't? The article is from 6 years ago. Are you sure the API is still available? I think Google Plus was shut down.

Comment: Sure that is very old, the project is legacy and login by Gmail is not working right now I had enabled the google plus API serval times and but but the issue not solved I got this error in google developer console. 

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/79DNS.jpg